# linq to entities joined tables not converting result into view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I would like to send all columns of both tables in my joined lINQ expression into my view.
It's basically a customer record along with the customers address record. It is in VB but a C# answer will do nicely.

I am uncertain if my approach is correct and cannot convert the result into what the view is expecting.

My result class is defined as

```
Partial Public Class CustomerContext
    Private m_customer As List(Of Customer)
    Public Property cust As List(Of Customer)
        Get
            cust = m_customer
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Customer))
            m_customer = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_address As List(Of CustomerAddress)
    Public Property addr As List(Of CustomerAddress)
        Get
            addr = m_address
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of CustomerAddress))
            m_address = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

My controller is defined as this:
        Function Details(Optional ByVal id As Integer = Nothing) As ActionResult

```
        Dim cc = (From c In db.Customers Join a In db.CustomerAddresses On c.CustomerID Equals a.AddressID
        Where (c.CustomerID = id)
        Select New CustomerContext With {.addr = db.CustomerAddresses.ToList, .cust = db.Customers.ToList})

        If IsNothing(cc) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If

        Return View(cc)

    End Function
```

And my View is

@Modeltype  MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerContext

```
<table>
<tr class="displayline">
<td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.cust.Item("Name"))
            </td>
            <td class="displaydatahalf">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.cust.item("Name"))
            </td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
            <td >
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.addr.item("address"))
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.addr.item("address"))
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The error message I get is

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerContext]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerContext'.

Comment: When I tried that sugestion I got an error from the return statement.

Comment: The error was LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerAddress] ToList[CustomerAddress](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerAddress])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Same thing here LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerAddress] ToList[CustomerAddress](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvCAdventureWorkTest.CustomerAddress])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I see, you cannot do `ToList` in your projection into CustomerContext. Change those properties to `IEnumerable` and remove `ToList` and try that.

Comment: This is where I really get lost. Which properties are you taking about, the CustomerContext class or the compenents of that class?

Comment: You are trying to select into `CustomerContext` using `db.CustomerAddresses.ToList` but L2E doesn't know how to transform `ToList` to a valid sql statement. That has to be removed and replaced with something else. Another option is to call `ToList` after your `Where` to force evaluation earlier

Comment: Adding a tolist after the where doesnt work syntactically. I however can load the individual properties of the context one by one with linq statements which does work but my main concern is to learn how to do it using the JOIN unles this isnt workable.

Comment: Can't you do this `.addr = db.CustomerAddresses` and change your `CustomerContext` property `addr` to an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Sure I guess, you mean both .cust and .addr to ienumerables in the customer context? I've seen far too many examples where they didnt do this so it has thrown me off. or like this                      Dim cc As New CustomerContext
cc.cust = (From c In db.Customers Where (c.CustomerID = id) Select c).ToList
cc.addr = (From a In db.CustomerAddresses Where (a.CustomerID = id) Select a).ToList()

Comment: OK I've made some progress with yu suggestions but the view failes on the reference to the addr properties...@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.addr.item("address"))
The ienumerable by iteself does get me down to the property level

Comment: What are you trying to do with your view? Display the `addr` and `cust` as a list?

Comment: No. Indivusla address the components -  @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.cust.Item(0).NameStyle) and  @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.addr.AddressID) but the lastoe does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that you cannot or cannot easily convery an object of type iqueryable to a usable type either ienumerable or list(of) but what does work is the following:

Dim cc As New CustomerContext
cc.cust = (From c In db.Customers Where (c.CustomerID = id) Select c).ToList
cc.addr = (From a In db.CustomerAddresses Where (a.CustomerID = id) Select a).ToList()

return view(cc)